# Running a postman-collection only starts the first one

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I have a postman collection with 3 requests in it. When I click on "Run Collection" normally all 3 requests are sent. Yesterday I figured out that only the first one is triggered, the others are ignored. I have cloned the collection, I have re-created the collection, I've updated postman... don't know what else to do..
I am on version 9.4.1 - maybe someone has an idea, thanks.

If someone wants to see my collection, here is the JSON-link: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/d8558e74dc154975151e
I've removed the API key for the requests.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**
I had to remove the `postman.setNextRequest` in my first request - this somehow broke it.

Comment: It would have set it to `null` or maybe a request name that was incorrect, which means stopping the run completely after that request. https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/#stop-workflow-execution